# Rails Assets, possible to have pre-compiled and non-compiled in production mode?

Tags: image, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-6

A Rails 6 app, production mode.

The situation is such that I have a number of image files that will be referenced in views.

Some I have in advance, and I can pre-compile and deploy these image assets with the app in production. No issues there.

However, the app when deployed and running will import more images from a remote source from time to time in an ad-hoc manner, those images will also be referenced in views.

So it looks like I would then have a mixture of pre-compiled and non-compiled images... doesn't 'feel' right.

I figure I could not pre-compile at all, and set

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

but the rails docu states this isn't recommended in Production mode.

I'm sure I'm not the first person to be trying to do something like this, and I'm wondering if I'm overlooking a tried and tested solution ?

Any ideas ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will likely want to store your images on a provider like S3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the images are fetched or compiled at runtime they don't belong in the assets pipeline. The whole point of the pipeline is to streamline the deployment and development process so that assets are automatically compiled/optimized at deploy time. Assets being files like CSS, JS and images that are a developer concern.

AFAIK Rails in its not possible to use both modes at once and neither would it be desirable as it would add significant overhead in production.

As mentioned in the comments these images should be stored separately from the assets pipeline and preferably in a cloud platform optimized for file delivery like S3 and not in your Rails app. Your app should just store URL's to these files.

There is no major difference here between how you would handle user file uploads and imports from a remote source except that the source is slightly different. Libraries like ActiveStorage and CarrierWave can do image transformations at runtime when the images are imported.